# Development Pipeline / Phases

Tags: web-development

I have been developing websites for quite sometime now, and I have now come to the stage where I want to run things properly.  I am trying to put together a proper workflow for my projects. I have come up with the following and would love any feedback or additions I haven't added.

1. Discovery and Research
2. Information Architecture
3. Interaction Design
4. Visual Design
5. Site Development
6. Quality Assurance
7. Launch, Wine and Cheese

Comment: perhaps here, it makes sense to differentiate between new and relaunch. I mean, in one case you might already have an existing website with content, in another you do not so you have to start from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Your current development line is quite good. My only advice is to sit down with the client and put real site data while doing stage 3. This will make your life easier in the future development and the client will be almost able to see how exactly data will look on the site.

Comment: Thank you for your advice ... I will be sure to implement it.

Comment: You may also find that doing the middle stages simultaneously is beneficial, i.e. instead of doing the visual design and signing it off, do it in tandem with the site development and constantly refine it.